# Export react Material table as pdf with an image on the header

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

I am trying to export a react MUI table as pdf with an image as part of the header information. When I export it without the image on the header, it is working fine, but when I source an image on the header, it shows on the browser but fails to export as PDF. How can I export the table with the with an image on the header part?

I used the documentation from  this site. https://material-table.com/#/docs/get-started

savings.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';
import useFetch from '../main/useFetch';
import ReportHeader from '../components/ReportHeader';

const Savings = () =>{
   
    const{data, isPending, error} = useFetch('/api/accounts/all_saving_savings');
    const columns=[
        
        {title: 'Name', field:'name', editable: 'never'},
        {title: 'CashIn', field:'CashIn', editable: 'onUpdate'},
        {title: 'CashOut', field:'CashOut', editable: 'onUpdate'},
        {title: 'Phone_no', field:'phone_no', editable: 'never'},
        {title: 'Type', field:'Type', editable: 'never'},
        {title: 'Status', field:'Status', editable: 'never'},
        {title: 'Save Date', field:'save_date', editable: 'never'},
    ]

    
    return(

        <div className='container-fluid'>
            {error && <div> {error} </div>}
            {isPending && <div>Loading...</div>}

            {data && <MaterialTable title={<ReportHeader h1 = 'Royal Focus All Savings' h2 = 'Savings Accounts'/>}
                data={data}
                columns={columns}
                options={{
                    search: true,
                    paging: true,
                    filtering: true,
                    exportButton: true,
                    sorting: true,
                    pageSizeOptions: [5,10,20, { value: data.length, label: 'All'}],
                    headerStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: '#495057',
                        color: '#FFF'
                    },
                    
                    
                }}
            />}
        </div>

    )

}
export default Savings;
```

the header component is as shown below.

```
import React from 'react'
import logo from '../images/LOGO.jpg'


const ReportHeader = ({ h1, h2 }) => {
    let date = new Date();
    return (
        <div className='p-2 m-2' >
            <div className='img-part'>
                <img className = 'img-fluid w-100 img-height' src={logo} alt=""/>
            </div>
            <p className='h5'>{h1}</p>
            <p className='h6'>{h2}</p>
            <div>{date.toISOString().slice(0, 10)}</div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ReportHeader
```